# codeigniter passing count_all_results to view

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm using the count_all_results() function to return a user's number of languages spoken. But when I try to pass the number to the view, I keep getting a php undefined variable (for $lang_cnt). Below is my code:

**Model**

```
function countLanguages($id) {

    $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->from('languages');
    return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

**Controller**

```
function showLangCount() {

    $data['lang_cnt'] = $this->language_model->countLanguages($id);

    $this->load->view('lang_view', $data);
}
```

**View**

```
<p>This user speaks <?php echo $lang_cnt; ?> languages.</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem is that your model function takes two arguments:

```
function countLanguages($id, $cnt_languages)
```

But when you call it you are only passing one argument:

```
$this->language_model->countLanguages($cnt_languages);
```

And an even bigger problem, as Rocket points out, is that `countLanguages` doesn't return anything. Try this:

```
function countLanguages($id) {
  $this->db->where('user_id', $id)->from('languages');
  return $this->db->count_all_results();
}
```

Comment: Also, `countLanguages` doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Rocket, thanks, that is indeed the cause of the problem. If you add it as an answer I will upvote and delete mine.

Comment: @Mischa - Thanks for your response. I've added the return language as suggested, and removed the 2nd argument. But I'm still getting the same error. I've updated my code to show the changes.

Comment: @Rocket - Thanks; I've added the return, but still get the same error. The code in my question has been updated to show the changes.

Comment: @chowwy, where is the `$id` in your controller coming from? Apart from not seeing where `$id` comes from I don't see any problems with the code you have posted. Could you show your complete code?

Comment: @Mischa - Thanks. The $id variable is the user id from the session data; it looks like this in the controller: $id = $this->session->userdata('user_id'); so it's pretty straightforward. There really isn't much more to show. I think the issue is that the controller isn't getting the count_all_results integer from the model.

Comment: @chowwy Try if it works if you return a hardcoded integer from your `countLanguages` function. If that works, you know the problem is with your `countLanguages` function. If it doesn't work, you'll know there is a problem in your controller code.

Comment: @Mischa - Tried it; looks like something is wrong with the controller. I can't figure out how to access the integer from count_all_results from the controller. The syntax I'm using is the same that I've used for other queries, and it works for everything but this count_all_results.

Comment: Does it work if you do this in the controller action: `$data['lang_cnt'] = 1;`?

Comment: @Mischa - Thanks for your help. At first it didn't work, but now it does. Turns out it was an error in one of my extended controllers. I marked your answer as correct because of the return issue. That would have solved it, if not for the other mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Always check your model functions if they return value or not. Try this:

```
function showLangCount() {
    if($this->language_model->countLanguages($id))
    {
        $data['lang_cnt'] = $this->language_model->countLanguages($id);
    }
    else
    {
        $data['lang_cnt'] = NULL;
    }

    $this->load->view('lang_view', $data);
}
```

Comment: `$this->db->count_all_results();` always returns an integer, so this should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Its better to use:

```
return $query->num_rows();
```

to return the number of rows effected...